# Increase computation speed for nested integral equations

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning, numerics, numerical-value

I want to numerically solve these two nested integral equations

$$q(J_0,T)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}\,\mbox{tanh}^2\left(\frac{z\sqrt{q(J_0,T)}+J_0 m(J_0,T)}{T}\right) dz$$

$$m(J_0,T)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}\mbox{tanh}\left(\frac{z\sqrt{q(J_0,T)}+J_0 m(J_0,T)}{T}\right) dz$$

and find the curve $Tc(J0)$ for which the following equation is satisfied:

$$T^2=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}\mbox{sech}^4\left(\frac{z\sqrt{q(h,T)}+J_0m(J_0,T)}{T}\right) dz$$

To do so I wrote the following code:

```
precision = 12;
Maxit = 100;
accuracy = Round[precision/2];
funJq[T_?NumericQ, J0_?NumericQ, m_?NumericQ, q_?NumericQ] := q - NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[2 Pi] Exp[-z^2/2] Tanh[SetPrecision[(Sqrt[q] z + J0 m)/T, precision + 1]]^2, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> precision, AccuracyGoal -> accuracy];
funJm[T_?NumericQ, J0_?NumericQ, m_?NumericQ, q_?NumericQ] := m - NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[2 Pi] Exp[-z^2/2] Tanh[SetPrecision[(Sqrt[q] z + J0 m)/T, precision + 1]], {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> precision, AccuracyGoal -> accuracy];
qfunJ[T_?NumericQ, J0_?NumericQ, m_?NumericQ] := Chop[FindRoot[funJq[T, J0, m, q], {q, 0.5}, MaxIterations -> Maxit][[1]][[2]]]
mfunJ[T_?NumericQ, J0_?NumericQ] := Chop[FindRoot[funJm[T, J0, m, qfunJ[T, J0, m]], {m, 0.5}, MaxIterations -> Maxit][[1]][[2]]]

fun3[T_?NumericQ, J0_?NumericQ] := T^2 - NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[2 Pi] Exp[-z^2/2] Sech[SetPrecision[(Sqrt[qfunJ[T, J0, mfunJ[T, J0]]] z + J0 mfunJ[T, J0])/T, precision + 2]]^4, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> precision, AccuracyGoal -> accuracy];

tfun2[J0_?NumericQ] := FindRoot[fun3[T, J0], {T, 0.7}, MaxIterations -> Maxit] [[1]][[2]];

hPoints2 = Table[{J0, tfun2[J0]}, {J0, 0, 0.9, 0.25}];
```

The solutions $q(J_0,T)$ and $q(J_0,T)$ are the expected ones, the problem is that the computation of the line $Tc(J_0)$ takes too long. I guess the problem is that "fun3" calls two times the function mfunJ, one outside qfunJ and one inside this last one, so the computation is really complicated. Is there a way to simplify it?

Comment: The obvious low hanging fruit is to parallelize the Table at the end, ie change `Table[...]`->`ParallelTable[...]` which should give some speedup for sure.

Comment: Thanks, it helps. On the other hand I was wondering if there exists a smarter way to this computation.