# Solving nested integral equations with NSolve

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics

I want to solve the following integral equations for $m$ and $q$, with parameters $J_0$
and $T$:
$$q(J_0,T)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}\,\mbox{tanh}^2\left(\frac{z\sqrt{q(J_0,T)}+J_0 m(J_0,T)}{T}\right) dz$$

$$m(J_0,T)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}\,\mbox{tanh}\left(\frac{z\sqrt{q(J_0,T)}+J_0 m(J_0,T)}{T}\right) dz$$

There is a way to solve them using FindRoot, but the computation time is very large, so I need an alternative. What I wanted to use is NSolve which can solve equations for multiple variables at the same time. I tried with the following code:

```
precision = 100;
Maxit = 500;
accuracy = Round[precision/2];
NSolve[{
 q == NIntegrate[
   1/Sqrt[2 Pi] Exp[-z^2/2] Tanh[SetPrecision[(Sqrt[q] z + 0.5 m)/0.5, precision + 1]]^2,
   {z, -Infinity, Infinity},
   WorkingPrecision -> precision,
   AccuracyGoal -> accuracy],
 m == NIntegrate[
   1/Sqrt[2 Pi] Exp[-z^2/2] Tanh[SetPrecision[(Sqrt[q] z + 0.5 m)/0.5, precision + 1]],
   {z, -Infinity, Infinity},
   WorkingPrecision -> precision, AccuracyGoal -> accuracy] },
 {q, m}]
```

but it seems that NSolve cannot use NIntegrate since it doesn't give any result. Can someone help me?

Comment: This looks very similar to [your other question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/285442/increase-computation-speed-for-nested-integral-equations)

Comment: (1) `FindRoot` can solve for multiple variables at the same time. (2) `NSolve` is not designed to solve such problems as this. (3) Why not code the `Tanh[]` factor as `Tanh[2 (Sqrt[q] z + m/2)]`? (It won't solve the root problem, but it makes the code easier to manage, imho.)

Comment: I worked on the original problem.  My conclusion was that the plots given in that post were quite accurate.  However it's based on using `FindRoot` which in my view is problematic as the routine may not converge to the desired root depending on what basin the seed is in.  However, if instead you used the values of that algorithm as seeds to a second iteration of `FindRoot` then the convergence problem is greatly reduced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somehow I thought this would be harder. Did I make a mistake?

`NumericQ`-protected integrals:

```
ClearAll[int, int2];
int[m_?NumericQ, q_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[
   1/Sqrt[2 Pi] Exp[-z^2/2] Tanh[2 (Sqrt[q] z + m/2)],
   {z, -Infinity, Infinity},
   WorkingPrecision -> precision, AccuracyGoal -> accuracy];
int2[m_?NumericQ, q_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[
   1/Sqrt[2 Pi] Exp[-z^2/2] Tanh[2 (Sqrt[q] z + m/2)]^2,
   {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> precision, AccuracyGoal -> accuracy];
```

Low-precision trial:

```
precision = MachinePrecision;
accuracy = Round[precision/2];
FindRoot[{q == int2[m, q], m == int[m, q]}, {{q, 1}, {m, 1/10}}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> precision]

(*  {q -> 0.530368, m -> -1.17503*10^-16}  *)
```

High-precision trial, with starting points from low-precision trial (wonder if `m == 0`?):

```
precision = 100;
accuracy = Round[precision/2];
FindRoot[{q == int2[m, q], m == int[m, q]}, {{q, 53/100}, {m, 1/100}},
  WorkingPrecision -> precision]
(*
{q -> 0.5303683920507946325937163727372733258213296547926817305857681565194767283477281152301036248598861080, 
 m -> -3.839206009833973918466466394691297613302158620963752726865098462765893379586940948647969930045448362*10^-116}
*)
```

Try with `m == 0`:

```
FindRoot[{q == int2[0, q]}, {{q, 53/100}}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> precision]

(*  {q -> 0.5303683920507946325937163727372733258213296547926817305857681565194767283477281152301036248598861080}  *)
```

Check:

```
int[m, q] /. % /. m -> 0

(*  0.*10^-101  *)
```

Comment: Don't see how that code is giving the variables $J$ and $T$ for the computed values of $q$ and $m$.

Comment: @josh The OP substituted special values for the parameters.  If the OP wants a different code to work, they should have posted it instead of what they did, imo. It's sort of a mess, and I'm not wading into that tar pit....

Comment: Oh I see that now.  Sorry.  Beautiful tar bit nevertheless. :)

Comment: I tried with specific values but the final goal is to compute $m$ and $q$ for $0<J_0<2$ and $0<T<2$, as @josh saw in the other post. Actually I needed a more efficient (less time consuming) way to tackle the problem to another similar situation where there are more nested integral equations

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively to MichaelE2's interesting answer you might use

```
- `NMinimize`

    J[q_?NumericQ, 
  m_?NumericQ] := # . # &[{q - 
    NIntegrate[
     1/Sqrt[2 Pi] Exp[-z^2/
        2] Tanh[ (Sqrt[q] z + 1/2 m)/(1/2) ]^2, {z, -Infinity, -10, 
      10, Infinity}, Method -> "GlobalAdaptive"], 
   m - NIntegrate[
     1/Sqrt[2 Pi] Exp[-z^2/
        2] Tanh[ (Sqrt[q] z + 1/2 m)/(1/2)], {z, -Infinity, -10, 10, 
      Infinity}, Method -> "GlobalAdaptive"]}]

NMinimize[ Re@J[q, m], {q, m}] // Quiet
(*{1.19349*10^-17, {q -> 0.530368, m -> 6.34778*10^-9}}*)
```

**addendum**

or

```
- `FixedPointList`

 
intqm[q_?NumericQ, m_?NumericQ] := { 
NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[2 Pi] Exp[-z^2/2] Tanh[ (Sqrt[q] z + 1/2m)/(1/2)]^2, {z, -Infinity, -10, 10, Infinity}, Method -> "GlobalAdaptive"], 
NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[2 Pi] Exp[-z^2/2] Tanh[ (Sqrt[q] z + 1/2m)/(1/2)],{z, -Infinity, -10, 10, Infinity}, Method -> "GlobalAdaptive"]}

FixedPointList[Apply[intqm, #] &, {1, 1}, 15]
(*{..., {0.530368, 0.0000164061}, {0.530368, 7.70484*10^-6}}*)
```

Both results agree well with MichaelE2's answer!